# Is it possible to prevent mulpitle method execution using custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I have a method that now looks like

```
private void DoOnce()
{
    if(executed)
        return;
    executed = true;
//    Some code here
}
```

Is it possible to hide this logic using, maybe, attributes.

That would look nice, if I could just add some attribute, e.g.

```
[ExecuteOnce]
```

that would do the same.

Is there a built-in support for such things in .Net Framework?

Comment: You can implement your own attribute that do this for you.

Comment: Emm. 
And how will it look like?
I mean, as I know, I can implement a custom attribute, but I will have to check it myself, using reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is someone that reads and understands your custom attribute *before* invoking method, yes.

But I think, unless this is not a common pattern in your program, you can continue do what you are doing now

1) `DoOnce()` explicitly describes behaviour of method

2) code inside is clear and understandable

**EDIT**

You may think also about alternative solution like:

```
 bool  IsInRecursion(string methodName) 
 {
   const int iCallDeepness = 1; 
   System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stack = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(false);
   System.Diagnostics.StackFrame sframe = stack.GetFrame(iCallDeepness);
   return (methodName == sframe.GetMethod().Name);
 }
```

and considering  `iCallDeepness = 1` you can use it like

```
void DoOnce() 
{
    if(IsInRecursion("DoOnce")) 
        return;

    ......
    ......
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, there is no way to do this using common methods calling, right?
I understand, that I can create my engine, that would check the attribute, and I would do all method calls using it, but it is not very comfortable.
That would be great, if I could create some attribute, that would be executed before the method call.

Comment: @ViktorArsanov: check my edited post and see if this works for you.

Comment: @ViktorArsanov: no there is no built-in support for such thing in .net, nor that I know.

Comment: @Tigran Isn't `StackTrace` very very expensive to execute?

Comment: @Maarten: the *real* cost of it depends on what you get from using it. I don't know how program of OP is structured and when and how the code is excecuted. I posted my edited answer like a possible alternative for OP to validate and not like a definitively correct answer.

Comment: @Tigran, that's I wanted to know, if there is a built-in support
Ok, thanks.
Maybe, you'll edit your answer and write that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use post sharp for executing some code on method entry and execute. But even using any attribute you need to set some global falg from your method like "executed", so I dont think using attribute would be much helpful.